# How to catch "like" number after user share from my application

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook application and allow user to share some data.

Therefore user will have a status that is shared by my application.

I wanna to catch this status "like" number.

Example,

user A ---> status A ---> 177 liked

user B ---> status A ---> 5 liked

PS.status A is shared by my application

Is it possible?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's possible. You just need the status ID. The query status_id/likes. It doesn't matter if it was posted through your app or not. I think you need the read_stream permission if it's not a fan page. Try here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ the easiest test is retrieve your fan pages (`me/accounts`), then get the feeds of one of them, (`page_id/feed`). It should be possible to get the `post_id/likes` as well. The number of likes comes with the page feeds, in the json object. If you just need the likes, you can get the likes only with post_id/likes.

Comment: If people share my application i can easily to get the "post_id"/ "status_id"?

Comment: indeed. Then just query postid/likes?

Comment: Yes, the most consider are people share my page then how many "like" his got.

Comment: Because i wanna to give them a rank.

Comment: well, as already said, you can do that. Accept the answer?